# Many pages with almost the same content but different in some area name keywords

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, geotargeting, pages

If I run a car fixing business which I can offers services to every part of USA. Then If I create 1000-1500 pages (or maybe higher than this) which each page has almost the same content but only the location name in each page is unique. Is this bad for SEO?

Example of pages:

- Car fixing service in Alabama `www.example.com/alabama`
- Car fixing service in Alaska `www.example.com/alaska`
- Car fixing service in Arizona `www.example.com/arizona`
- Car fixing service in Delaware `www.example.com/delaware`
- Car fixing service in Georgia `www.example.com/georgia`
- and so on ............

The pages may even go deeper in to city or ever deeper like:

- Car fixing service in Jefferson City `www.example.com/jeffersoncity`

Inside these pages the main content are 100% the same but the names of the state or city written in the content are changed according to each page target area.

By doing this, is there any bad effect on SEO?. As if i finish all the state names, cities or even more deeper i might have around 1000-1500 pages with the same format.